# Conert Php 5.6 to 7.2 getting error - Too few arguments to function Mymodel::mymodelfunction(), 0 passed in

Tags: php, codeigniter

My project running on `PHP 5.6`. 
But now I need to covert this project in `PHP 7.2`.
So when I converted it in `PHP 7.2` then I have facing argument initialization error

> "Too few arguments to function Mymodel::mymodelfunction(), 0 passed in"

Because this argument is not defined as the default value.

This is not working on local environments give the same error.

But when I run this code in the server then this is working fine.

So please suggest me,
what can I do in local environments to strict error reporting.

Comment: Why don't you fix the error by passing a value? Are you saying it works on the server because that's still running 5.6?

Comment: server also in 7.2 where this is woking, if try to define default value of funation then i need to do lots of work on all the working functions. So it is not posible to change all functions parameters

Comment: Then don't set a default. Pass a value.

Comment: I think your sql-mode is set to 'strick' which is not allowing you to send empty value. Either set default value in database or send NULL from your controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply change the signature from:

```
class Mymodel
{
    public static mymodelfunction ($argument1)
    {
        (...)
    }
}
```

to

```
class Mymodel
{
    public static mymodelfunction ($argument1 = '')
    {
        (...)
    }
}
```

make sure to pass correct fallback value (sometimes array might be needed, not string). This way you will provide a fallback (default) value if you don't pass params.

More details about the core source of your issue is available on PHP manual page:
http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php

Comment: or $argument1= null or $argument1=0 depending of the argument type

Comment: Bro I know this method but this is not posible to update all functions.
plz suggest any other method to solve this issue.
it is posible to solve this issue using "strict error reporting"?

Comment: @furkanali89 if you want to stop getting exceptions the easiest way is to run your app with the same PHP version as is on your server, which is probably anything pre-7.1. It only started to be exception in php 7.1. You asked to convert it to 7.2 and part of code conversion to 7.2 is defining functions correctly the same way your code uses it, which is why I suggested editing the code.

Comment: Thanks @janmyszkier. This is working when I used PHP 7.0 version. Thanks for support.